# Use only certain fixture parameterizations in different tests in pytest

Tags: python, fixtures, pytest

I have a fixture called `n_groups` that I would like to parameterize in some cases, but not in others. The reason for this is because the way my MVC-like data model is structured, I test as much as I can in the "model" classes, but the "controller" classes don't need as extensive of testing because I've already done it in the "model." So running the tests with all the parameterizations is redundant in the controller, and I'd like to limit the number of tests and thus the testing time. Currently for testing the initialization of my controller, over 18,000 tests are generated, and it takes 42 minutes to run! See the [Travis-CI output](https://travis-ci.org/YeoLab/flotilla/builds/45581395).

Currently, my workaround is to do,

```
# Contents of conftest.py
import pytest
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

@pytest.fixture(scope='module', params=[2, 3],
                ids=['2_groups', '3_groups'])
def n_groups(request):
    """Number of phenotype groups.

    For testing that functions work when there's only 2 groups
    """
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def n_groups_fixed():
    """Fixed number of phenotype groups (3)"""
    return 3
```

Then, I pass either `n_groups` or `n_groups_fixed` to the next chain of fixtures which create data for testing. The `outliers`, `pooled`, `samples`, `n_samples` and `metadata_phenotype_col` fixtures are also parameterized, but are out of the scope of this question.

```
# Contents of conftest.py
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def groups(n_groups):
    """Phenotype group names"""
    return ['group{}'.format(i + 1) for i in np.arange(n_groups)]

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def groups_fixed(n_groups_fixed):
    """Phenotype group names"""
    return ['group{}'.format(i + 1) for i in np.arange(n_groups_fixed)]

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def groupby(groups, samples):
    return dict((sample, np.random.choice(groups)) for sample in samples)

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def groupby_fixed(groups_fixed, samples):
    return dict((sample, np.random.choice(groups_fixed)) for sample in samples)

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def metadata_data(groupby, outliers, pooled, samples,
                  n_samples,
                  metadata_phenotype_col):
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=samples)
    if outliers is not None:
        df['outlier'] = df.index.isin(outliers)
    if pooled is not None:
        df['pooled'] = df.index.isin(pooled)
    df[metadata_phenotype_col] = groupby
    df['subset1'] = np.random.choice([True, False], size=n_samples)
    return df

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def metadata_data_groups_fixed(groupby_fixed, outliers, pooled, samples,
                  n_samples,
                  metadata_phenotype_col):
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=samples)
    if outliers is not None:
        df['outlier'] = df.index.isin(outliers)
    if pooled is not None:
        df['pooled'] = df.index.isin(pooled)
    df[metadata_phenotype_col] = groupby_fixed
    df['subset1'] = np.random.choice([True, False], size=n_samples)
    return df
```

It seems rather cumbersome to have a `*_fixed` version for each of these fixtures.

Examples of the tests would be an extensive test within the data model testing both parameterizations of `n_groups`, and a less extensive test within the controller, which only tests one "parameterization" using `groups_fixed` (these are not the real tests, just examples for demonstration):

```
# Contents of test_model.py
class TestModel(object):
    def test__init(metadata_data, ...):
        ...

    def test_plot(metadata_data_fixed, ...);
        ...

# Contents of test_controller.py
class TestController(object):
    def test__init(metadata_data_fixed, ...):
        ...
```

Is there another way to do this? I've read pytest's [parameterize](http://pytest.org/latest/example/parametrize.html#paramexamples) documentation, but it only seems to set parameterizations globally, and not on a per-test basis.

I'd like to do something like:

```
# Contents of test_model.py
class TestModel(object):
    def test__init(metadata_data, ...):
        ...

    @pytest.mark.parameterize(n_groups=3)
    def test_plot(metadata_data, ...);
        ...

# Contents of test_controller.py
class TestController(object):
    @pytest.mark.parameterize(n_groups=3)
    def test__init(metadata_data_fixed, ...):
        ...
```

UPDATE: Adding an `n_groups` fixture within `TestController` doesn't help, i.e. this doesn't work:

```
# Contents of test_controller.py
class TestController(object):
    @pytest.fixture
    def n_groups():
        return 3

    def test__init(metadata_data_fixed, ...):
        ...
```

I'm not sure why, because it seems that this fixture should overwrite the global `n_groups` defined in `conftest.py`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do that with the builtin `parametrize`, I think you will have to implement a custom  parametrization scheme based on some information about the method being tested (for instance, if a class contains `Controller` in its name you would parametrize it differently), using the [pytest_generate_tests hook](http://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_generate_tests). Some examples can be found [here](http://pytest.org/latest/parametrize.html?highlight=pytest_generate_tests#pytest-generate-tests).

Comment: Thanks! That works for `TestController` because I can have that in the file `test_controller.py`, and would apply to all tests in the file. For `TestModel`, would I think inspect `metafunc.function.__name__` to check there? It seems this kind of thing could be encapsulated in a decorator for test functions. Do you know if such a feature is planned in `pytest`?

Comment: Yes, check for metafunc.function.__name__ would work. I don't think there are any plans to implement this as a built-in decorator, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea was correct and using parameterize to overwrite a fixture value will take effect across the whole fixture chain.

The following reduced example works  such that it will run the first tests based on the parameterized `n_groups` fixture twice and the second test only once for the passed value from the test parameterization. (add `-s` to your pytest call to see the print output)

```
# Contents of conftest.py
import pytest
import numpy as np

@pytest.fixture(params=[2, 4],
                ids=['2_groups', '4_groups'])
def n_groups(request):
    """Number of phenotype groups.

    For testing that functions work when there's only 2 groups
    """
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture
def groups(n_groups):
    """Phenotype group names"""
    return ['group{}'.format(i + 1) for i in np.arange(n_groups)]

def test_groups(groups):
    print(groups)


@pytest.mark.parametrize('n_groups', [3])
def test_groups_fixed(groups):
    print(groups)
```

As to why it did not work in your example I suspect it might be due to different fixture parameter names. When you use the fixture `n_groups_fixed` but call the parameter `n_groups` in your test parameterization it will not work.